# Is it "Commercial Use" when I use an image viewer software on a company laptop, but only for private purposes?

Tags: software, licensing

A lot of software is provided "free for personal use, licensed for commercial use".

For example, the *FastStone Image Viewer* is provided with [these conditions](https://www.faststone.org/order.htm):

> FastStone Image Viewer ... provided as **freeware for personal and educational use**. In these cases, you are granted the right to use these programs free of charge. However, for **commercial use, license is required**.

Is it a commercial use when I install the software on my company computer and use it only to view my personal photos? (Of course supposed that the employer does not have a problem with using the company laptop for personal use, too.)

Comment: I know that is unlikely to be discovered, but how would you prove that software installed on your company laptop is *not* being used for comercial purposes?

Comment: @PeterM Is it me who has to prove it? Is the fact that the software is installed on my work computer a sufficient proof that I am using it for "commercial use", if I am a backend programmer and my work does not consist of any picture handling?

Comment: IMHO By having that software on your work laptop it is reasonable for Fastone to ask the question "Is it for personal use?", at which point, yes, it is up to you (and your company) to prove that it is only being used for personal use.  Try to imagine how you would explain it to a judge, when they don't know or care what your role technically is.  Of course that is predicated on Fastone being 1) aware of your usage, and 2) caring enough to ask the question.

Comment: Then again, if it is decreed that using that viewer is not private use, the implication is that you viewing your personal photos on the company computer is not private use?!

Comment: What happens if it associates itself with image file types and accidentally opens a file while at work, or a work-related file at any time? Some sorts of software might obviously have no relation to your work - e.g. if you install software to control your knitting machine and your work does not involve knitting - but an image viewer is far too general for it to be clearly not work related.

Comment: And anyway: FastStone will show thumbnails of adjacent folders. It won't know which are yours and which are the company's. But first, you must ask the company about using their property for personal use (and risking their data too).

Comment: Whether or not it's technically "commercial use" should probably be irrelevant *to your company*, because what it almost certainly *is* is an "unnecessary risk". Any half-way competent IT manager should tell you "don't do that" to avoid any possibility of the company getting into trouble...

Comment: @brhans At least in my social bubble it's **absolutely normal** that IT companies tolerate their programmers the personal use of the company laptop. If my employer forbade me this, I would just change the employer. Programmers are generally tolerated to use the company laptops at least to browse the internet and watch movies and their personal photos.

Comment: @brhans Oh, now I realize that I might have misunderstood your comment! By the "unnecessary risk", did you mean "technical risk in using the company laptop for personal use", or "legal risk in using software with such licensing policy"?

Comment: I meant the legal risk to the company from the use of software with such a license on company equipment. The fact the you would use this software on company equipment would make it the company's problem to defend against the software's creator if they should decide to make an issue of it. From the company's point of view, that should be an unnecessary risk, and they should ask you not to use that software on their equipment (if they have any sense).